# How to use date range in presto

Tags: presto

I have to select DS (datetimestamp) from year to year.

Example:

```
SELECT  
id_product, 
code,
substr(ds_date, 1,10) as date,
product_type,
from Table A
where 1=1
AND ds <='2019-12-31'
AND (ds_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2019-12-31')
groupby 1,2,3,4
```

Is it right way to declare DS range in presto?

Answer (score 1):

If `ds_date` is a varchar of the form `yyyy-MM-dd...`, then this is readable:

```
substr(ds_date, 1, 4) BETWEEN '2017' AND '2019' -- inclusive: 2017, 2018, 2019
```

However, this prevents predicate pushdown on `ds_date` into data source, so this may be more performant:

```
ds_date >= '2017' AND ds_date < '2020'
```